# IBM RAD 9.5 cannot start after Scala IDE plugin installed

Tags: eclipse, ibm-rad, scala-ide

I use IBM RAD 9.5, and installed Scala IDE recently via Eclipse Marketplace.
Right after that RAD stopped starting:

[image]

The log content is like that:

```
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin is not a Java .class file
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:215)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:124)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.Utility.makeJavaClass(Utility.java:467)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:515)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.ensureDelegateInitialized(WeavingAdaptor.java:513)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor$WeavingClassFileProvider.<init>(WeavingAdaptor.java:843)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:526)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.loadtime.OSGiWeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.AspectJWeavingService.preProcess(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.adaptors.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hooks.WeavingHook.processClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    ... 26 more
```

Then I googled that this might help, and it indeed helps:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP_1\jdk\bin>java.exe -Xshareclasses:destroyAll

Attempting to destroy all caches in cacheDir C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\javasharedresources\

JVMSHRC256I Persistent shared cache "IBMSDP_barat" has been destroyed
```

But the solution works only until IBM RAD is closed, next time I have to repeat.

What I try to achieve: how to make IBM RAD start without explicit cleaning shared classes? The `-clean` key in IBM RAD 9.5 shortcut makes RAD start, but no Scala related views work at all.

UPDATE. Versions of plugins:
[image]

Comment: What version of Scala IDE are you installing?

Comment: I am not sure I had a choice. The one which RAD returned in marketplace search. See the version in screenshot in UPDATE